# Value isn't being brought over

Tags: java

So when I enter a value in for the second question my program just stalls and nothing happens. If I enter a value for the first question, then enter a wrong value for the second, then try to cancel out of the program it gives me my display method (which it shouldn't unless the value is allowed).

What's going wrong in my program?

```
    while (invalidInput) {
        //Try...catch block to find any input errors for the number.
        try {
            finalNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a number between 1 and 20",
                    "The Word Factory", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            while (finalNum != null) {
                finalNumber = Integer.parseInt(finalNum);
                if (finalNumber > 20 || finalNumber < 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number you entered was not between 1 and 20."
                                    + " \nPlease try again.",
                            "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    finalNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Please enter a number between 1 and 20",
                            "The Word Factory", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    Part2 object = new Part2(finalString, finalNumber);
                    object.answer2 = finalString;
                    object.number2 = finalNumber;
                    object.display();
                }
            }
            invalidInput = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number you entered was not between 1 and 20."
                            + " \nPlease try again.",
                    "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe the logic is backward? tell us the expected input and output with an example

Comment: also the if only goes in there if an incorrect answer is input.

Comment: it seems you want to break out of your while loop if the value is valid but you don't have an else.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix some of your logic. You were in an infinite loop since there was no way to ever break out of it. I fixed this by making a valid number boolean. Also why the outer while loop? That increases the time complexity for no reason. So got rid of it and replaced with an if

```
if (invalidInput)
            finalNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                     "Please enter a number between 1 and 20",
                    "The Word Factory", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
             boolean valid = false;
            while (valid == false)
            {
                finalNumber = Integer.parseInt(finalNum);

                if( finalNumber > 20 || finalNumber < 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number you entered was not between 1 and 20."
                    + " \nPlease try again.",
                   "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                    finalNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                     "Please enter a number between 1 and 20",
                    "The Word Factory", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    Part2 object = new Part2(finalString, finalNumber);
                    object.answer2 = finalString;
                    object.number2 = finalNumber;
                    object.display();
                }
             else
               valid = true;

            }

        }
```

Comment: This works; however, if you enter a 0 it will bring up the error message, and after that if you try to cancel out of the program it will bring up the error message again. <-- This shouldn't happen

Comment: I think it is because of your catch.

Comment: since you try to exit out of the while look while the value still isnt valid it is caught again when you exit and thus the catch is fired.

Comment: I see, so how could I get around that?

Comment: you dont need the catch at all. it makes no sense to be honest. i edited the code again

Comment: Okay, I'll use your code when I get the chance and let you know if it works.

Comment: So I used your code, but the thing is, is that I need a try...catch to catch any exceptions (it's part of my assignment requirement)